# SQLAlchemy - create table statement with indexes

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to produce a `CREATE TABLE` statement using `postgresql` and `sqalchemy`. Columns are correctly created but indexes are missing.

What am i missing ?

Here is the snipper of code i am using...

```py
    table = Table('test', metadata, 
                  Column('id', Integer), 
                  Column('booking', Integer, index=True))
    create_stmt = CreateTable(cls.table).compile(connection)
    print(create_stmt)
    # This print CREATE TABLE test ( id INTEGER, booking INTEGER)
    # Index on column booking is missing
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `CreateIndex` over the indexes of the table.

```py
    from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
    from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
    
    metadata=MetaData()
    ​
    table = Table('test', metadata, 
                  Column('id', Integer), 
                  Column('booking', Integer, index=True))

    
    create_stmt = CreateTable(table).compile(session.connection())
    print(create_stmt)
    
    CREATE TABLE test (
        id INTEGER, 
        booking INTEGER
    )

    
    from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateIndex
    for index in table.indexes:
        create_stmt2 = CreateIndex(index).compile(session.connection())
        print(create_stmt2)

    CREATE INDEX ix_test_booking ON test (booking)
```

This solution is not so clean and a bit annoying, honestly, but I wonder if there is any reason why you are not using the full schema creation, something like `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that's what i am using right now but it doesn't seem natural. As for create_all, i am aware of its existence but in thise case i don't want to use it

Comment: @Irnzcig, would you happen to know how to pull this off with Oracle and `CreateSequence` ?

Comment: Hi @MatthewMoisen, I don't have a setup right now to test easily with Oracle, but looking at it quickly it seems there is a `CreateSequence` in `sqlalchemy.schema`. I guess it should work pretty much the same?

Comment: Thanks. If you know which column contains the sequence in advanced, you can do `CreateSequence(mytable.c.id.default)`